# Quick question about filter_xss()

Tags: nodes, forms

If I'm creating nodes programmatically does Drupal deal with `filter_xss()`, or do I have to add the function to my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sanitization functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/sanitization/7), which include [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7), are used when a value is shown as output, not when something is saved in the database.

None of those functions is called when saving a node in the database.

See [Writing secure code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code).

> #### Use check functions on output to prevent cross site scripting attacks
>
> No piece of user-submitted content should ever be placed as-is into HTML.
>
> - Use [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_plain) or [theme('placeholder')](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_placeholder) for plain text.
> - Use [check_markup()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_markup) or [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_xss) for markup containing text.
> - Use the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) function with @ or % placeholders to construct safe, translatable strings.